# Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

When my app launches I have the following error `Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys` regarding my dictionary:

```
private let errorsDescriptions: [ErrorType: String] = [
        .networkError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.networkErrorDescription)),
        .productRecognizerError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.productRecognizerErrorDescription)),
        .loginError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.loginErrorDescription)),
        .registerError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.registerErrorDescription)),
        .firstTimeLoginError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.firstTimeLoginErrorDescription)),
        .emailPasswordSignInError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.emailPasswordSignInErrorDescription)),
        .phoneSignInError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.phoneSignInErrorDescription)),
        .googleSignInError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.googleSignInErrorDescription)),
        .facebookSignInError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.facebookSignInErrorDescription)),
        .githubSignInError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.githubSignInErrorDescription)),
        .logoutError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.logoutErrorDescription)),
        .changeEmailError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeEmailErrorDescription)),
        .changePasswordError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changePasswordErrorDescription)),
        .deleteAccountError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.deleteAccountErrorDescription)),
        .discountApplyError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.discountApplyErrorDescription)),
        .orderCreateError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.orderCreateErrorDescription)),
        .biometricRecognitionError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.biometricRecognitionErrorDescription)),
        .applyProductRatingError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.applyProductRatingErrorDescription)),
        .returnCreateError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.returnCreateErrorDescription)),
        .createAddressError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.createAddressErrorDescription)),
        .changeDefaultAddressError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeDefaultAddressErrorDescription)),
        .changeDefaultPaymentMethodError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeDefaultPaymentMethodErrorDescription)),
        .changePhotoError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changePhotoErrorDescription)),
        .dataFetchError:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.dataFetchErrorDescription)),
        .unknown:
            TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.unknownDescription))
    ]
```

Where `ErrorType` is an `Enum` of:

```
enum ErrorType: String {
    case networkError
    case productRecognizerError
    case loginError
    case registerError
    case firstTimeLoginError
    case emailPasswordSignInError
    case phoneSignInError
    case googleSignInError
    case facebookSignInError
    case githubSignInError
    case logoutError
    case changeEmailError
    case changePasswordError
    case deleteAccountError
    case discountApplyError
    case orderCreateError
    case biometricRecognitionError
    case applyProductRatingError
    case returnCreateError
    case createAddressError
    case changeDefaultAddressError
    case changeDefaultPaymentMethodError
    case changePhotoError
    case dataFetchError
    
    case unknown
    
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        return nil
    }
    
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .networkError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.networkError))
        case .productRecognizerError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.productRecognizerError))
        case .loginError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.loginError))
        case .registerError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.registerError))
        case .firstTimeLoginError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.firstTimeLoginError))
        case .emailPasswordSignInError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.emailPasswordSignInError))
        case .phoneSignInError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.phoneSignInError))
        case .googleSignInError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.googleSignInError))
        case .facebookSignInError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.facebookSignInError))
        case .githubSignInError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.githubSignInError))
        case .logoutError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.logoutError))
        case .changeEmailError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeEmailError))
        case .changePasswordError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changePasswordError))
        case .deleteAccountError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.deleteAccountError))
        case .discountApplyError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.discountApplyError))
        case .orderCreateError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.orderCreateError))
        case .biometricRecognitionError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.biometricRecognitionError))
        case .applyProductRatingError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.applyProductRatingError))
        case .returnCreateError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.returnCreateError))
        case .createAddressError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.createAddressError))
        case .changeDefaultAddressError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeDefaultAddressError))
        case .changeDefaultPaymentMethodError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changeDefaultPaymentMethodError))
        case .changePhotoError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.changePhotoError))
        case .dataFetchError:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.dataFetchError))
        case .unknown:
            return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(.unknown))
        }
    }
}
```

In all above `TexteriftManager.localisedString()` method returns `String` value.
I can't see where I have duplicated any keys. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

UPDATE:

Implementation of `TexteriftManager.localisedString()` method:

```
public static func localisedString(key: Localizable) -> String {
        if let localizationBundle = Bundle(path: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/\(bundleName)") {
            return NSLocalizedString(key.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: localizationBundle, value: "", comment: "")
        } else {
            return customBundle.localizedString(forKey: key.rawValue, value: "", table: nil)
        }
    }
```

Where `Localizable` is another `Enum` which has `rawValue: String`.

Comment: What strings does TexteriftManager.localisedString() return for each of these (write a little program and print them out)? I expect two or more of the mare the same.

Comment: The ideal way to debug this is to delete all the values but two. Does that compile? Then add half the values. Does that compile? If not, add the other half. Binary search it until you find what the problem is. But also the fact that `init?(rawValue:)` returns `nil` in all cases makes me very suspicious of your design (which seems to require a surprising amount of duplicated code; I'd dig into how to simplify and improve that ).

Comment: As for duplicate code, a safer solution would be to isolate the `TexterifyManager.localizedString()` calls in a utility function (like `localize()`) of the `ErrorType` enum, and just use the cases everywhere else. For example, instead of using localization to parse the `rawValue`, don't implement `rawValue` at all, and instead call something like `ErrorType.changeDefaultAddressError.localized()` when you need to display it.

Comment: @RobNapier What does it matter what `TexteriftManager.localisedString()` does return? It is used as value in dictionary. Values can be duplicated, keys can't as the error states. 
I removed `init?(rawValue:)` from my enum as it wasn't necessary.
What's more, I tried Your binary removal method of dictionary entries and started from having only dictionary consisting of only two first keys and the problem remained :(

Comment: I also updated post by adding implementation of `TexteriftManager.localisedString()` method

Comment: If your `Bundle` paths are invalid – a `Bundle` in the Documents folder looks pretty odd anyway – you get an empty string for each value. And can `rawValue` not be reduced to one line `var rawValue: String { return TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .errors(self)) }`?

Comment: I'd didn't mean "what's the implementation." I mean, what values does it return. Two of them are the same. As vadian notes, if you have any errors, then you return `""`, and that would cause duplicates keys in the Dictionary. You probably mean to set `value` to nil anyway. That way it'll return the key on error instead of `""` (though you may want to catch errors, too).

Comment: I tried @RobNapier "binary search" method and I figured out that `unknown` value of `ErrorType` enum causes problem. I changed it's name to `unknownError`, making respective change in other files it occured and it is working now. Don't know why exactly `unknown` was a problem. Is it some keyword used somewhere?